# tvOS - Live video streaming stops due to playbackBufferEmpty and never resumes

Tags: ios, avplayer, tvos, playback, avplayerviewcontroller

I'm using default AVPlayerController to play my video in my tvOS. [tvOS 12.1.1]

Sometimes due to bad network or bandwidth issue, the video stops to play due to playbackBufferEmpty.

In that case, I observed that

1. **playbackLikelyToKeepUp = false**
2. **playbackBufferFull = false**
3. **playbackBufferEmpty = true**
4. **playerView rate is 0.0**
5. **playerView timeControlStatus is paused**
6. **playerView reasonForWaitingToPlay is AVPlayerWaitingToMinimizeStallsReason**

After that, the video freezes and doesn't resume to play even after when bandwidth resumes.

Is this a bug from the player or we need to programmatically trigger to resume the video is it stops to play?

Once playbackBuffer empty occurs, I am calling this function handleBufferEmptyCase()

Even after calling this function, I have observed the video still gets paused and never resumes.
Cases that I have observed when video freeze, if I try to play another video, the video plays without any interruption for at least 45 mins and again the video is frozen.
I have a good bandwidth to play live streaming.

## Code snippet:

```
func observeCurrentPlayingVideo() {
    if currentItem.status == AVPlayerItem.Status.readyToPlay {
        if currentItem.isPlaybackLikelyToKeepUp {

        } else if currentItem.isPlaybackBufferEmpty {

            print("LiveVC | isPlaybackBufferEmpty...")
            perform(#selector(handleBufferEmptyCase), with: nil, afterDelay: 2)

        }  else if currentItem.isPlaybackBufferFull {

        }

    } if currentItem.status == AVPlayerItem.Status.failed {

    }
}


func handleBufferEmptyCase() {
        if let currentItem = self.playerView.currentItem {
            if currentItem.isPlaybackBufferEmpty && !currentItem.isPlaybackLikelyToKeepUp && playerView.rate != 1 && playerView.timeControlStatus == .paused {
            print("handleBufferEmptyCase | Triggering to play again...")
            self.playerView.pause()
            self.playerView.play()
        }
    }
}
```

My expectation is to continue playback and make sure the video continues even after bufferEmpty happens.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, when `AVPlayer` stop playing because of bad connection, `AVPlayerItem` has a failed status. You must create a new `AVPlayerItem` object and use `replaceCurrentItem(with:)` `AVPlayer` method.

The relevant way to know about the player "status" is to check the associated `AVPlayerItem` rate. 0 means player has stopped. rate != 0 means player is playing.

Also, use `AVPlayerItem`'s notifications to detect something's wrong:

- AVPlayerItemPlaybackStalled
- AVPlayerItemFailedToPlayToEndTime
- AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime (can be triggered when buffer is empty **AND** network is out)

This iOS library [ModernAVPlayer](https://github.com/noreasonprojects/ModernAVPlayer) can help you to understand the process.
Check the `PlayingState.swift` file and associated services.